# How to rewrite this in dart to avoid the cast error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this piece of code, I want to return a stream of documentshapshots.

```
/* Get Firestore products docs
 */
  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchFirstProductListStream() {
    
    ....
   return  getFirestoreUserStream(loggedInUser.uid).map((UserModel rad) => 
    (geo
          .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
          .within(center: center, radius: rad.radius, field: field)) as List<DocumentSnapshot>
    );
}
```

I do get the following error as I try to cast the return value to List.

```
> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type
> '_AsBroadcastStream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>' is not a subtype of type > > 'List<DocumentSnapshot>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

**Option1:**
As you have finally converted the data into a plain list. return that directly. You dont need a `Stream` or a `StreamBuilder` to parse that now. You can directly use a `ListView.builder()` to render the data:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> fetchFirstProductListStream() {
    
....
   return  getFirestoreUserStream(loggedInUser.uid).map((UserModel rad) => 
    (geo
          .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
          .within(center: center, radius: rad.radius, field: field)) as List<DocumentSnapshot>
    );
}
```

**Option 2:**
Return a true `Stream` from the API and use a `StreamBuilder` to read it asynchronously:

Checkout this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393146/firestore-collection-query-as-stream-in-flutter):